# JPA Hibernate delete orphan in entity-relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity-relationship

I have a problem with JPA. I can't delete staff object from database like this:

```
// trying to delete from my jsp this person-staff (commit error)
Staff del = em.find(Staff.class, staff.getId());    
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.remove(del);
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
emf.close();
```

or change it:

```
Staff staff... // get changed data from html form
MyCompositePK temp = new MyCompositePK();
String[] parts = author.split(" ");
temp.setFirstName(parts[0]);
temp.setSurname(parts[1]);
temp.setPatronymic(parts[2]);
Staff change = (Staff) em.find(Staff.class, temp); 

em.getTransaction().begin(); 
change.setId(staff.getId());
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
emf.close();
```

MyCompositePK is embedded id for Staff class. Here a my entities:

```
@Embeddable
public class MyCompositePK implements Serializable {

    @Column
    private String surname;
    @Column
    private String firstName;
    @Column
    private String patronymic;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Here is Staff class declaration:

```
//imports

@Entity
public class Staff {

    @EmbeddedId
    private MyCompositePK id;
    private Date birthday;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="POST_ID")
    private Post post;
    @Lob
    @Column(length = 100000)
    private byte[] photo;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Here is my document (I also have another two documents, they inherit Document class), which contains fields with Staff(ManyToOne).

```
package documents;

//imports    

@Entity
@Table(name = "incomings")
public class Incoming extends Document {    

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "sender_firstname",    referencedColumnName = "firstname"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "sender_surname", referencedColumnName = "surname"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "sender_patronymic", referencedColumnName = "patronymic") })
    private Staff sender;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "destination_firstname", referencedColumnName = "firstname"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "destination_surname", referencedColumnName = "surname"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "destination_patronymic", referencedColumnName = "patronymic") })
    private Staff destination;

    private int outgoingNumber;     
    private Date outgoingRegDate;

    //getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Входящий документ" + "\r\n");
        sb.append(super.toString());
        sb.append("Отправитель" + sender.toString() + "\r\n");
        sb.append("Адресат" + destination.toString() + "\r\n");
        sb.append("Исходящий номер" + outgoingNumber + "\r\n");
        sb.append("Исходящая дата регистрации" + outgoingRegDate.toString() + "\r\n");
        sb.append("Текст документа" + super.getContent() + "\r\n");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

So, can I delete Staff object directly?

Comment: Have you defined `hashCode()` and `equals()` method for the `MyCompositePK`?

Comment: No. They are not mandatory. You can switch to warning in your IDE

Comment: As far as I know, they must be defined for composite keys.